# Ubuntu:NetBeans:OpenCV:Shared library not found

Tags: opencv, shared-libraries, ubuntu-10.04, netbeans-7

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1 with C++ on NetBeans 7.1 on Ubuntu 11.04 (Gnome).  When I add the call

cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D

and try to run the program in Debug mode I get the error message

/home/peter/NetBeansProjects/ArtifactImgFromCellFile/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/artifactimgfromcellfile: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_calib3d.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This despite the fact that I have libopencv_calib3d.so.2.3 in

/home/peter/OpenCV-2.3.1/lib

On NetBeans I went to

Properties:Linker:Run Time Search Directories

and added

/home/peter/OpenCV-2.3.1/lib

but that did not fix the problem.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Netbeans you explicitly also need to link the library as follows.

1. Right click the project and open properties.
2. Go to Build -> Linker
3. Go to Libraries -> Add library file.
4. Browse to where your library is, i.e. the .so file. In your case it should be at /home/peter/OpenCV-2.3.1/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks very much.  I thought that I had added all the libraries in that directory since I had followed the steps that you had outlined but just did ctrl-A to add all the files in the directory.  But it may have just been showing the .a files so was not adding files ending in so.2.3